# how to insert images and icons in to index file in Angularjs 4.0 should i create saparate component for it?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am working on a task I want to insert a menu icon in to the index page.
when I click on the icon I want to show menu list with icons only on mouse out I want to hide it. So how to call images icons from different folders. Should I create component for images. I am confused. When I click on the menu icon I want to toggle the menu list.

```
<img [src]="icon">
<li><a routerLink="home"><img ng-src="images/icon.png" src="{{image}}"></a></li>
```

Comment: Put your image in assets folder from that you can access your image

Comment: can u give the syntax

Comment: something like this  -   src="./assets/images/logo.svg"

Comment: yeh i done the same thing it's working how to apply css for it should i use ng-class

Answer (score 0):

something like this -

```
 `src="./assets/images/logo.svg"`
```

all css, js , images should be kept in Assets folder. read document, yopu will be more clear about this

Comment: how to fire click event on it, like this (click)

Comment: i created saparate css file for it how to call it should i declare in app.module.ts, how?  applied like this <img src="./assets/menuicon.png" ng-class="menuicon"> but iam not able to apply css for it